# Django IOError failed to write data - Exception occurred processing WSGI script

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, ioerror

```
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error] [client 178.161.91.227] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: mod_wsgi (pid=941): Unable to get bucket brigade for request.
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error] Internal Server Error: /profile/
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]   File "/sites/virtualenvs/capstone/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]   File "/sites/virtualenvs/capstone/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]   File "/sites/virtualenvs/capstone/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]   File "/sites/virtualenvs/capstone/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]   File "/sites/virtualenvs/capstone/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 466, in dispatch
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]     response = self.handle_exception(exc)
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]   File "/sites/virtualenvs/capstone/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 463, in dispatch
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]     response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]   File "/sites/projects/capstone/app/views.py", line 258, in get
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]     pk = request.data.get('pk', None)
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]   File "/sites/virtualenvs/capstone/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 353, in __getattribute__
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]     return super(Request, self).__getattribute__(attr)
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]   File "/sites/virtualenvs/capstone/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 183, in data
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]     self._load_data_and_files()
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]   File "/sites/virtualenvs/capstone/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 243, in _load_data_and_files
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]     self._data, self._files = self._parse()
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]   File "/sites/virtualenvs/capstone/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 289, in _parse
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]     parsed = parser.parse(stream, media_type, self.parser_context)
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]   File "/sites/virtualenvs/capstone/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/parsers.py", line 66, in parse
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]     data = stream.read().decode(encoding)
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]   File "/sites/virtualenvs/capstone/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 322, in read
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]     six.reraise(UnreadablePostError, UnreadablePostError(*e.args), sys.exc_info()[2])
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]   File "/sites/virtualenvs/capstone/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 320, in read
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]     return self._stream.read(*args, **kwargs)
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]   File "/sites/virtualenvs/capstone/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 47, in read
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]     result = self.buffer + self._read_limited()
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]   File "/sites/virtualenvs/capstone/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 41, in _read_limited
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error]     result = self.stream.read(size)
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error] UnreadablePostError: request data read error
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error] [client 178.161.91.227] mod_wsgi (pid=937): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/sites/projects/capstone/project/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Dec 12 10:45:23 2016] [error] [client 178.161.91.227] IOError: failed to write data
[Mon Dec 12 14:18:18 2016] [error] Not Found: /
[Mon Dec 12 20:15:04 2016] [error] Not Found: /etc/lib/pChart2/examples/index.php
[Tue Dec 13 07:01:55 2016] [error] Not Found: /
[Tue Dec 13 07:01:55 2016] [error] Not Found: /
[Tue Dec 13 07:14:10 2016] [error] Not Found: /
[Tue Dec 13 07:14:11 2016] [error] Not Found: /
[Tue Dec 13 07:39:17 2016] [error] Not Found: /
```

This is the latest part of my error_log in the server. This error pops up randomly (I can't see a pattern). I researched a ton and couldn't find a solution, tried countless things found googling and nothing really worked. One thing that kind of worked for a bit then stopped working is to change the value of "Timeout" in the apache config file and increase it, it's now at 600. It solved the problem at the time, then the problem came back. First time I came across it, I changed the URI endpoint in the Django code and the name of the view function, but kept the same old code, and the problem went away. But it came back again later.

I'm using Django==1.9.6 and MySQL-python==1.2.5 and Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x86_64 Minimal)

The following is the entry in the access log that caused this error to pop up.

```
178.161.91.227 - - [12/Dec/2016:10:45:13 +0000] "GET /profile/ HTTP/1.1" 500 637 "-" "Capstone-Project/1.0 (alebrahim.Capstone-Project; build:1; iOS 10.1.0) Alamofire/4.1.0"
```

I don't know what else is relevant, if there's any info needed I'll add it here.

edit: We noticed that this problem only occurs when the Alamofire request encodes the request object as JSON. If it's not encoded, this problem goes away.

Comment: How long does it normally take to process the request at `/profile/`? Do you know as which user 178.161.91.227 was logged on at the time the error occurred? If you log on as that user and try to visit `/profile/`, how long does it take to respond and what is the result?

Comment: It doesn't take exceptionally long, it takes the same usual time other requests take. This is part of a mobile app, the frontend iOS app uses Alamofire to handle the requests. There are no users in the application, just me (backend dev) and my friend (frontend dev). That's it, no one is using this. I can (and will) find out which user account was used and take that into consideration. The result of the response is what I posted there. The frontend receives a number of bytes. Nothing else. Weird I know, but I'm thinking it might be the length of the html error code (debug is set to True).

Answer (score 0):

Both errors are caused by the HTTP client dropping the connection before the request had been completed. This could cause the request body to have been truncated causing the read error, or a write error in case of connection having been closed. It is quite normal for this to happen and there is nothing in your application you can do to stop it as it is caused by a deliberate action of the user at the other end, or possibly a network issue in between.

Comment: Or maybe a timeout?